# How to Post to friend's Timeline

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to a friend's wall, without any success

Error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xa799fa0
>   {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403,
>   com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey=(
>           {
>           body =         {
>               error =             {
>                   code = 200;
>                   message = "(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application";
>                   type = OAuthException;
>               };
>           };
>           code = 403;
>       } )

Login process in LoginViewController:

```
-(IBAction)facebookButtonPressed:(id)sender {    
    [facebook authorize:[self permissions]];
}

- (NSArray *)permissions {
    static NSArray *pms;
    if (pms == nil) {
        pms = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"user_photos", @"user_location", @"user_birthday",
               @"friends_birthday", @"friends_location", @"friends_photos", @"user_relationships",
               @"publish_actions", @"publish_stream", nil];
    }
    return pms;
}
```

Code for posting to friend's timeline in PostViewController:

```
- (void)postToFriendWall:(NSString *)userId {
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc]initWithAppId:APP_ID andDelegate:self];

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [facebook setAccessToken:[defaults objectForKey:FB_ACCESS_TOKEN]];
        [facebook setExpirationDate:[defaults objectForKey:FB_EXPIRATION_DATE]];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *defaultWish = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", DEFAULT_WISH, [defaults objectForKey:FB_USER_ID]]];
    NSString *defaultImage = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", DEFAULT_IMAGE, [defaults objectForKey:FB_USER_ID]]];

    if (defaultImage == nil && defaultWish == nil) {
        [self showAlertViewWithTitle:@"Post wasn't sent" message:@""];
        return;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];
    [params setObject:defaultWish forKey:@"message"];
    if (![defaultImage isEqualToString:@"none"])
        [params setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:defaultImage] forKey:@"picture"];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", userId] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
}

- (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:FB_ACCESS_TOKEN];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:FB_EXPIRATION_DATE];

    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *errorDescription = [error description];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
}

- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled{
}

- (void)fbDidLogout{
}

- (void)fbSessionInvalidated{
}

- (void)fbDialogLogin:(NSString *)token expirationDate:(NSDate *)expirationDate {
}

- (void)fbDialogNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/), posting of Friend's wall has been depreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of February 6, 2013, you can't post to Friend's Timeline with that Graph method.

Read Here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

Look for [feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), [user mentions tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/) or [Open Graph Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) as an alternative.

Comment: What??? So, you are telling me that I can't post to a friend wall, just mention him as a tag or post to my own wall?!

Comment: yes you can't, read it for yourself on that link. You can make use of the alternatives if they suit your needs.

Comment: can't I post to a friend via FBWebDialog?

Comment: yes you can use, it's already listed in the alternatives list(Feed Dialog).

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but I mean without mention him as a tag, something like sending parameters with "to" and user ID, I am getting "cannot post to user's wall"

Comment: it should work, here's a direct URL example: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=458358780877780&link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&to=UserID&redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: ThePCWizard - thanks, tried to use your url in code, se my answer bellow.

Comment: @assafey still not through?, If yes please close this question by marking an answer.

Comment: @assafey, You will get "cannot post to user's wall" erros if they have disallowed others to post to their wall/timeline in their privacy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and got an error:

```
- (void)showFeedDialog {
    // Put together the dialog parameters
    NSMutableDictionary *params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"MY_APP_ID", @"app_id"
     @"feed", @"method"
     @"USER_ID", @"to",
     @"try", @"caption",
     @"https://develo‌​pers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
     @"try link", @"name",
     @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
     @"Using%20Dialogs%2‌​0to%20interact%20with%20users.", @"description",
     @"https://mighty-lowlands-638‌​1.herokuapp.com/", @"redirect_uri",
     nil];

    // Invoke the dialog
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil//[FBSession activeSession]
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             // Case A: Error launching the dialog or publishing story.
             NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                 NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
             } else {
                 // Case C: Dialog shown and the user clicks Cancel or Share
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                     // User clicked the Cancel button
                     NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                 } else {
                     // User clicked the Share button
                     NSString *postID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"];
                     NSLog(@"Posted story, id: %@", postID);
                 }
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: remove the "redirect_uri" parameter. Try with a different user as he may have the "Who can post on your timeline?" setting set to "Only me". Please post the complete error, if any now.

Comment: Checked the user "Who can post on your timeline?" - It is set to Friends, and I am a friend. redirect_url removed. Still getting an error, can't catch the error, it is shown on the dialog itself: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=68uauc&s=5

Comment: Wow!! The problem was with the commas between the NSDictionay objects. But now I can't include a message to the dialog, "message" parameter seem to be not working

Comment: great it worked, but why you need the `message` parameter? It is NOT supported for this dialog.

Comment: Because I want the user just press Send/Publish, and the text to post on the friend wall will be from a text field in the app. Can't I do it? Is there any dialog that support it?

Comment: No, use the `description` or `caption` instead.